# ZPL: combination of counter and fixed text into QR code

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

I need to create a ZPL code to create a QR code consisting of a fixed text and a counter (serialization).

I'm using http://labelary.com/viewer.html to test my ZPL syntax.

```
^XA^LH200,300
^BQN,2,7^FD
^SNBag_0001,1,Y
^PQ2,0,1,Y
^FS
^XZ
```

The QR code is created and the serial number works, but the content is _0001. the "Bag" text is skipped. "Bag" is just an example, the actual fixed text is much longer.

Any idea how to make this work?
Kind regards, Michael

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you are contenting with here. Maybe these will help.

QR code using SN command with the underscore. (I'm not sure why, but the 'aaa' is required here. I'v spent 30 min trying to find an answer, I'll come back and find one later.)

```
^XA^LH200,300
^BQN,2,7
^SNaaaBAG_0001,1,Y^FS
^FO50,300
^CF0,100
^SNBAG_0001,1,Y^FS
^PQ10,0,1,Y
^XZ
```

DataMatrix using the SF command allows for underscore, might be easier to understand.

```
^XA
^FO250,120^A0N,50,50
^BXN,10,200
^FDBAG_0001^SF%%%%dddd^FS
^FO250,300^A0N,50,50
^FDBAG_0001^SF%%%%dddd^FS
^PQ500
^XZ
```